# catching IO exceptions in servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I use `servant` for a simple JSON api, that allows you to create users, whose names must be unique. This is enforced by a unique constraint in SQLite. I have a function `DB.saveUser :: UserReq -> IO Int` that (unsurprisingly) saves users to SQLite and returns the generated id. It will throw a `SQLError ErrorConstraint _ _` if the name has already been taken. I want to return a HTTP response code 409 if that occurs. So my question would be, is there some way to catch the `SQLError` in the Handler Monad? If not, what would be the cleanest way to achieve what I'm looking for? I thought about making `DB.saveUser` return a `Maybe Int` but somehow I think there must be a better solution.

```
createUser :: UserReq -> Handler (Headers '[Header "Location" Text] NoContent)
createUser ur = do id <- liftIO (DB.saveUser ur)
                   return . addHeader (T.pack ("/user/" ++ show id)) $ NoContent

saveUser (UR.UserReq name) = withConnection database $ \conn ->
  do executeNamed conn "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (:name)" [":name" := name]
     fromIntegral <$> lastInsertRowId conn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servant's `Handler` is a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype Handler a = Handler { runHandler' :: ExceptT ServantErr IO a }
```

inside, there is a `ExceptT ServantErr`, where `ServantErr` is:

```
data ServantErr = ServantErr { errHTTPCode     :: Int
                             , errReasonPhrase :: String
                             , errBody         :: LBS.ByteString
                             , errHeaders      :: [HTTP.Header]
                             } deriving (Show, Eq, Read, Typeable)
```

So, you can run your DB operations in eg `try` or, to handle releasing resources: `bracket`, and map your DB exceptions to `ServantErr` to get the HTTP response code that you want.

How to throw `ServantErr` after you catch DB exception: https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#failing-through-servanterr